# Why Json format is such like this?

Tags: json

[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"rice\",\"productCode\":\"1101\",\"unitPrice\":1.00,\"condition\":\"NEW\",\"description\":\"this is real need\",\"createdAt\":\"Mar 17, 2017\",\"unitInStock\":5},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Gentle Park\",\"productCode\":\"1102\",\"unitPrice\":1000.00,\"condition\":\"NEW\",\"description\":\"test shirt\",\"createdAt\":\"Mar 21, 2017\",\"deletedAt\":\"Mar 21, 2017\",\"unitInStock\":10}]

i try to get list of json object but when i call from post man this shows such message. How can i remove '\' from json data?

Comment: json file used with which language

Answer (score 2):

Open your chrome dev tool, go to console, user " wrap postman string, "[postman string]", you will get readable string.

As you can see postman has several way to show json format from response.
try to view it in preview or pretty mode

[image]